# Android disable autocomplete for a certain string

Tags: android, autocomplete, autocompletetextview

I have an AutoCompleteTextView set up right now, but I want to prevent it from auto-completing a certain string (the user has to input it manually to get a result).  Right now it is auto-completing for the entire list, but I was wondering if there is any way to make the auto-completion selective.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although I haven't done this myself, but i think if you provide your own implementation of getFilter method in Adapter you can control if any results will be shown or not. So basically you will define the class

```
public class AutoCompleteAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String> implements Filterable
```

and then override getFilter method

```
@Override
public Filter getFilter() {
    Filter myFilter = new Filter() {
        @Override
        protected FilterResults performFiltering(CharSequence constraint) {
        ......
        }

        @Override
        protected void publishResults(CharSequence contraint, FilterResults results) {
        ....
        }
```